# Don't join a table if column value doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
`wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`firstName`
, `wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`city`
, `wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`state`
, `wp_posts`.`post_content`
, `wp_posts`.`post_date`
, `wp_posts`.`post_type`
, `wp_posts`.`ID`
, `wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`permission`
, `wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`userID`
, `wp_users`.`user_login`
, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`
FROM
 `wp_emu_theme_testimonials`
INNER JOIN  `wp_emu_theme_contact_page` 
    ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`contactID` = `wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`dbID`)
INNER JOIN  `wp_posts` 
    ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`postID` = `wp_posts`.`ID`)
LEFT JOIN  `wp_users` 
    ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`userID` = `wp_users`.`ID`)
INNER JOIN  `wp_usermeta` 
    ON (`wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`)
WHERE (`wp_posts`.`post_type` ='testimonial'
AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` ='facebook_uid')
OR (`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'null');
```

The  problem is that table `wp_usermeta` might not have a meta_key = 'facebook_uid'.  In that case, I am not getting those entries.  I want to get all the other stuff, even if that `meta_key` doesnt exist for that `user_id`.  And if it does, great. This query works as expected if I take out the parts regarding that table.  I've tried without the OR.  I am using mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `LEFT JOIN` and make that conditional part of the `ON`:

```
LEFT JOIN  `wp_usermeta` 
    ON (`wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`
        AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` ='facebook_uid')
```

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood your intentions.

Comment: Yes, thankyou.  I modified the last join as you suggest and got rid of the last AND and ON.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
`wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`firstName`
,`wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`city`
, `wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`state`
, `wp_posts`.`post_content`
, `wp_posts`.`post_date`
, `wp_posts`.`post_type`
, `wp_posts`.`ID`
, `wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`permission`
, `wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`userID`
, `wp_users`.`user_login`
, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`
FROM
`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`
INNER JOIN  `wp_emu_theme_contact_page` 
ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`contactID` = `wp_emu_theme_contact_page`.`dbID`)
INNER JOIN  `wp_posts` 
ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`postID` = `wp_posts`.`ID`)
LEFT JOIN  `wp_users` 
ON (`wp_emu_theme_testimonials`.`userID` = `wp_users`.`ID`)
LEFT JOIN  `wp_usermeta` 
ON (`wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`)
WHERE (`wp_posts`.`post_type` ='testimonial'
AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` ='facebook_uid')
OR (`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` IS NULL);
```

Use Left join in this situation instead of inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I use T-SQL (MS SQL Server), not MySQL, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

I am not sure that you are checking for null correctly:

```
OR (`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'null');
```

Can you check for NULL that way? in SQL Server you need to use IS NULL to check, and this article (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm) seems to say that it is the same in MySQL. If you change the or to say somthing like

```
OR (`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` IS NULL);
```

you might get what you want. ALso, I am not sure how parens work in MySQL, but I would do it like this:

```
WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` ='testimonial'          
AND (`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` ='facebook_uid' OR `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` IS NULL);
```

Now, having said all of that, you should still consider making it a left join to the table, as others have suggested. It might give you better performance than using an or anyway.