# perform a JOIN if joined field has a value

Tags: mysql, join

After googling and looking on SO I came out with a not working solution for a specific type of query. I have a table that is used to convert a value from another table in a text. Let's say:

```
id - text
1 - House
2 - Villa
3 - Camper
```

and the main table is

```
id - valueA - valueB - valueC
1 - 1 - whastington - 3000
2 -  - NewYork - 5000
```

So if I fetch row frm the main table I replace the values for valueA from 1 to House and so on.

ValueA is set on specific conditions. In any other case it will be left blank (the field is not intended to be NULL).

If I do the join the second row will be left out because valueA is blank. The query is

```
SELECT id,text,valueB,valueC FROM main JOIN dic on main.valueA =  dic.id
```

so I tried to say: ***perform the join only if valueA is not blank***
and I wrote this condition as:

```
SELECT id,text,valueB,valueC FROM main 
JOIN dic ON (main.valueA =  dic.id AND main.valueA <>'')
```

as I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877218/dont-join-a-table-if-column-value-doesnt-exist) but I did not get what I want, probably because the AND condition in that case was based on another field and not on the joined one. I can add another row in the dictionary table with a 0 - NONE couple and turn all the empty valueA to 0 but I'd like to learn if I'm on the right path with my query and what I am doing wrong. This so called "conditional join" is possible in mysql?
I also had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948812/mysql-conditional-join-depends-on-a-column) but this solution would make this query too complicated for it's purpose and in this case I'd go for the "plan B" of replacing empty with 0

Comment: What is your expected result from the example data?

Comment: I want to select both rows from main. With plain join I miss row 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand your goal. It seems to me that you just need `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT main.id,
  dic.text,
  main.valueB,
  main.valueC 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN dic 
on main.valueA =  dic.id
```

**UPDATE** if you want to see `dic.id` in query result, just add that field in `SELECT` part as welll as `valueA` from `main` if needed :

```
SELECT main.id,
  dic.text,
  dic.id DIC_ID,
  main.valueA MAIN_VALUEA,
  main.valueB,
  main.valueC 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN dic 
on main.valueA =  dic.id
```

DIC_ID and MAIN_VALUEA just aliases for columns, you can set your own names or leave it blank.

Comment: Yes. Left join is another option. But in case the condition is not "not blank" but "not a specific value"? Do you have to put it into the where condition with no other option?

Comment: @LelioFaieta It works for any value that doesn't appear in `dic.id`.

Comment: If in dic.id I have 1,2 and 3 and I want to do the join only for 1 and 2 and leave 3 instead of its text in the main table? 3 is in both tables and the join'd work but I don't want to do the replacement for 3

Comment: **WHAT?** there is no such thing as **replacement** in this particular context. if you want to get `dic.id` for current record. just `SELECT` it. check update.

Comment: replacement = text instead of valueA = perform the join

Comment: Can't get your point. describe with some data sample please. Update your OP please, and show expected result that you can't reach yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` to combine the `JOIN` with a query that gets all the rows with empty `valueA`.

```
SELECT id, text, valueB, valueC
FROM main
JOIN dic ON main.valueA != '' AND main.valueA = dic.id
UNION
SELECT id, '', valueB, valueC
FROM main
WHERE main.valueA = ''
```

Comment: Good point but why do you also add main.valueA != '' in the first SELECT?

Comment: I suppose it's redundant, but it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subquery to do this (or LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT text FROM dic WHERE dic.id = main.valueA), -- will return NULL of not found, use IFNULL if you want another value to be returned -- 
valueB, 
valueC
FROM main
```

Comment: Subquery will affect performance! Left join in this specific case is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but to then use an IF to return different values for the valueA column (either the valueA or the text)

Something like this:-

```
SELECT main.id,
        IF(dic.id IS NULL, main.valueA, dic.text)
        main.valueB,
        main.valueC 
FROM main 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dic on main.valueA =  dic.id
```